# QT Creator QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I want to run a fortran executable that is called when I click in push button in the interface that I created.

Although when I click in the button nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString program = QDir::currentPath() + "/PARROT/Console1.exe";
process->start(program);
```

The string is in that way because I want to be capable of changing the path to the main executable and the fortran executable.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through these lines with a debugger to verify that `program` contains the expected path?

Comment: No, I just run the program.

Comment: you can attach slot to readyReadStandardError() signal and see what's error is coming

Comment: Stderr probably doesn't report anything. But connect to the finished() and error() signals and check errorString()

Comment: Try to use `QString program = QString("cmd /C %1%2").arg(QDir::currentPath()).arg("/PARROT/Console1.exe")`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:fortran]? For the question, it doesn't really matter where the executable comes from...

Comment: What's the value of `program` when you pass it to process ?

Comment: thanks I had already figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link - [QProcess Start command syntax](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start)

syntax - **void QProcess::start(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments, OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)**

You need to pass the argumentlist as 2nd parameter,along with the process path as 1st parameter, needed to start the process.